# which file type is "7a7e656a" magic number?

Tags: python, pdfminer

I want to extract all the images present into the PDF file. I have tried several libraries such as fixz, pdfminer, minecart etc. but none of them give satisfactory results

using code of pdfminer as per  https://denis.papathanasiou.org/archive/2010.08.04.post.pdf, when I try to print bytes_as_hex, it returns "7a7e656a" which is not in the global list of all the file signatures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) so how to proceed further to get the correct extension of this image and save it?

```py
def determine_image_type (stream_first_4_bytes):
    """Find out the image file type based on the magic number comparison of the first 4 (or 2) bytes"""
    file_type = None
    bytes_as_hex = b2a_hex(stream_first_4_bytes)
    bytes_as_hex = (bytes_as_hex).decode('utf-8')
    print(bytes_as_hex)   #output: 7a7e656a
    if bytes_as_hex.startswith('ffd8'):
        file_type = '.jpeg'
    elif bytes_as_hex == '89504e47':
        file_type = '.png'
    elif bytes_as_hex == '47494638':
        file_type = '.gif'
    elif bytes_as_hex.startswith('424d'):
        file_type = '.bmp'

    return file_type
```

online tool PDF Candy (https://pdfcandy.com/pdf-ocr.html) is able to extract all the images of input file. and I want to get the similar output. ref file containing 4 images (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A6v-FJXW_ujEBCvY1HTa1TodGZKy5QAo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: maybe it uses some compression or it is not image file but some raw data used only in PDF to keep image.

Answer (score 0):

the following command gave the expected output with coordinates of the image saved in the xml file and images to be saved in local system. (the default zoom factor is 1.5 so, I have explicitly written 1 to not have any factor in consideration)

```
pdftohtml -xml -zoom 1 file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

"7a7e656a..." is the actual pixel values of one of your images.

To see this:

1. Use pdftohtml to pull out the images:

   pdftohtml -zoom 1 -xml 1.pdf
2. This produces four files:

   1-1_1.png   1-1_2.jpg   1-2_1.png   1-2_2.jpg
3. Convert the png to pbm:

   pngtopnm 1-1_1.png   > 111.pbm
4. Examine the pbm:

   od -h 111.pbm |head

   0000000      3650    350a    2035    3437    320a    3535    **7a**0a    **657e**

   0000020      6e**6a**    6855    556c    6663    6c53    5c6f    6967    655b

If you look at the decompressed flatedecode streams in the original pdf you can see it right there, look for

```
/W 55
/H 74
/BPC 8
/CS /RGB
ID
z~ejnUhlUc......
```

Why pdftohtml recognizes that and turns it into a png, I can't say.